# Simple Counter using Dialogflow Conv.Data or Conv.User.Storage

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am looking to create a super simple counter in a conversation in a firebase function using actions for google.

the [documentation](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#data) recommends:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
   conv.data.someProperty = 'someValue'
})
```

However, **typescript** does not recognise any kind of dot notation after conv.data as a value, and does not allow the code to deploy.

however, as far as I can determine, using

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
 conv.data["someProperty"] = 1;
})
```

Does, but doesn't seem to permit counting the int...

I have tried:

```
conv.data['currentIndex'] = parseInt(conv.data['currentIndex']) + 1;


conv.data['currentIndex'] = parseInt(conv.data['currentIndex'])++;


conv.data['currentIndex'] += 1;
```

I feel I am missing something super fundamental here.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly specify types of variables you want to use.

Try defining interfaces like:

```
//use this in conv.data

interface ConvData {
  counter?: number  
}

// use in conv.user.storage
interface UserStorage {
  location?: string
  name?: string
}
```

and initializing the app as:

```
const app = dialogflow<ConvData, UserStorage>({ debug: true })
```

and then using

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
   conv.data.counter = 1
})
```

Reference: [Actions on Google TS sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/935d0f9adfe78a4f9eb83ab4bb0fb9f6a7db2001/samples/ts/app/name-psychic/functions/src/index.tsx).